# Specflow - same test to be repeated for multiple logins

Tags: selenium, specflow

I am automating a web application - we are using specflow for writing the specs and selenium/nunit for automation.
The issue I am having is this.
Each scenario needs to be run on multiple browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, safari etc) and quite a few tests(if not all) need to run for multiple logins. How do I design my specflow scenarios to satisfy both needs.

I thought about using tags for browsers and Scenario Outlin/Examples for multiple logins. Is this the only way. How do you address this need in your project?

My example scenario:

```
@IE10 
@IE11
@Chrome
Scenario Outline: Check audit trail for XXXX function
Given I am on the <role> homepage
When I do some ation YYYY
Then The expected result is ZZZZ

Examples:
|role|
|doctor|
|nurse|
|pharmacist|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue with the SpecFlow+Runner.
Have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39344970/3155323

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these as terminal argument like:
`gradle clean test - Dapp.browser.type="chrome"`